# A Ghost File on my website

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

We have three IIS 7.5 server running on Windows 2008, R2, 64-bit OS.  Recently we have a problem with the two of them in relation to a one .htm file.  For some reason the site seems to serve an older version of the file even though the file on the local drive is a newer version.  If I were to delete the file and then hit the URL in the browser, I still get the old version displayed instead of a 404 or page not found.

I am new to IIS 7.5 and have delete the folder from the C:\Inetpub\Temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files and still no luck.

Any idea where this particular file may be cached?  I have searched all drives on the computer and there are no other copies.

Comment: Do you have a proxy in the mix?

Answer (score 2):

There's Output Caching in IIS 7.5 which you can configure in IIS Manager. I'd check there first to see if there's anything configured.
Make sure that you don't have a proxy hosting service like CloudFlare for the site too, that one's gotten me before.
Another thing to check is for any proxy/caching server on the network. If you're overlooking an ISA server and looking at the site on the network it could actually be gone already.

Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager:
On the taskbar, click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

In the Connections pane, go to the connection, site, application, or directory for which you want to configure page output caching.

In the Home pane, scroll to Output Caching, and then double-click Output Caching.

In the Actions pane, click Add...

In the Add Cache Rule dialog box, type the file name extension you want to cache in the File name extension box, and then select the User-mode caching option, the Kernel-mode caching option, or both.

Select the options that you want to use for caching, and then click OK.

Hope that helps!

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching

Comment: Our site is straight forward containing the content that is majority static.  The page having issue is a .htm file.  There are no proxy or ISA server in between.  Output caching is not configured at any level, site, application or directory.  I have used procmon utility but for the file in question, I do not see any activity.  All other files show up when accessed by w3wp.exe.  We will use wireshark next to see if and how the file is accessed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet that you're seeing your web browser cache the content, rather than an issue on your server.

Comment: We checked that also.  We made sure that the browser is not caching the content.  Tested it with FireFox and IE 10.  Used F12 to run a debugger in IE10 and cleared the cache but still getting old content.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the content is actually being served by IIS? You can do this by checking the log files. If there is a cache or other proxy between you and the server (which could be transparent proxy, put in place by your ISP, that you can't normally see our a reverse proxy nearer the other end) then it could be handling the request and never sending it to the web server even though your local cache definitely isn't used.

Comment: I have used procmon to capture activity on the server but it does not show file being accessed.  We don't have an ISP.  The entire site is hosted in our datacenter.  I am hitting the site directly using the IP address of the site as a URL in the browser.  There are three hops to the site.  Two gatways and a Firewall.  Unless the firewall is caching the content which I know it does not I don't this that is an issue.   Also, this issue is only happening with one file and not with any others.  Thanks.